# laravel unique name says already taken if you edit/update that particular object

Tags: laravel, unique, crud

I have a table Portfolios and instead of showing the id of the portfolio in the url I show the name of the portfolio with getRouteKeyName(). So I want the name to be unique because else it can show the wrong portfolio if it already exists. I set up the rules for the name field to be unique. If I now edit/update the portfolio it says: "The name is already taken."

How can I resolve this? It needs to be unique but if you updating that portfolio without changing the name it should't say that, right?

**Model Portfolio:**

```
public function getRouteKeyName()
{
    return 'name';
}
```

**PortfolioRequest:**

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:30|unique:portfolios',
    ];
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to pass an extra attribute to rules

```
public function rules()
{
    return [
        'name' => 'required|max:30|unique:portfolios,name,'.$name.
    ];
}
```

`$name` is the variable that you want to skip.

Hope this helps

Comment: Yea, just found a similar solution: 'name' => 'required|max:30|unique:portfolios,name,' . $this->portfolio->id,

Comment: @EnzoTrompeneers $this->portfolio->id it is not accessible in Request class